# QT5 Change Flat style color

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I am using PyQt5 and QML and using the Flat style. How would I change the overall color so it's not green? So far it seems my options are either create my own custom components or use the style as is.

Comment: It seems QT labs controls might have better support for overall theming. Trying to figure out if PyQt5 supports QT labs controls now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FlatStyle properties are read-only and thus, cannot be modified.

As suggested by @egfconnor, consider [Qt Quick Controls 2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html) (in 5.7) or its tech preview "Qt Labs Controls" (in Qt 5.6) instead. They are currently shipped with [three styles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html):

- [Default style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-default.html) - a simple and minimal all-round style that offers the maximum performance
- [Material style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html) - a style based on the Google Material Design Guidelines
- [Universal style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-universal.html) - a style based on the Microsoft Universal Design Guidelines

While the colors in the first one are not configurable to achieve maximum performance, the latter two have configurable themes and colors with natural inheritance.

Comment: Are the QT Labs Controls in 5.6 available in PyQt? I'm not having any luck on Windows getting them to work. I have however got them to work in straight C++ QT/QML.

Comment: I suppose this also applies to C++ base QT and QML as well.  Is this correct?  Bummer to find out about this now.

Comment: @Encompass Could you elaborate? What is "C++ base Qt and QML"?

Comment: @jpnurmi In this question he was speaking about pyqt with qml.  I am created an application with c++ and qml.  In particular trying to change the styles of the Flat example to meet my needs. I am using qt5.7